# C# function reference to an overloaded method

Tags: c#, static, overloading, pass-by-reference

I have a static class with a few overloaded methods. I was wondering if there was a simple/elegant way of passing reference to the correct overloaded method to another method of mine.

ObjectComparer.cs:

```
internal static class ObjectComparer {
    internal static void AssertAreEqual(Company expected, Company actual) {
        // ...
    }

    internal static void AssertAreEqual(Contact expected, Contact actual) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

CollectionComparer.cs:

```
internal static class CollectionComparer {
    internal static void AssertAreEqual<T>(List<T> expected, List<T> actual, Action<T, T> comparer) 
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count, actual.Count);

        for (var i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++) 
        {
            comparer(expected[i], actual[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

CompanyRepositoryUnitTest.cs:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAllCompaniesTest()
{
    // some work that creates 2 collections: expectedCompanies and actualCompanies

    // I am hoping I can write the following method 
    // but I am getting an error over here saying 
    // The best overloaded method ... has invalid arguments
    CollectionComparer.AssertAreEqual(expectedCompanies, actualCompanies, ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual);
}
```

---

### **EDIT**

It turns out the compiler was complaining about one of my other arguments: actualCompanies. It was a ICollection instead of List.

*Apologies. This was a very silly mistake.*

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling the type for your method? `CollectionComparer.AssertAreEqual<Company>(expectedCompanies, actualCompanies, ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual);` given i dont think you should have to but... worth the try

Comment: I did as shown in the code sample above. It turns out it wasn't  ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual that was causing the trouble. It was one of my other parameters, which was ICollection<UserInvitation> instead of List<UserInvitation>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would also help, if your comparer is static and never changes, you might not have a need to pass it every time.

```
internal static class CollectionComparer {
internal static void AssertAreEqual<T>(List<T> expected, List<T> actual) 
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count, actual.Count);

        for (var i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++) 
        {
            CollectionComparer.AssertAreEqual(expected[i], actual[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was what I initially had however (despite all of this living in my test code) I felt it was violating the Single Responsibility Principle. ObjectComparer compares state of objects where as CollectionComparer compares state of the collections (i.e. number of elements, and equality of elements).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to instantiate the `Action` as follows while passing as `AssertAreEqual` parameter:

```
var action=  new Action<Company,Company>(ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual);
CollectionComparer.AssertAreEqual(expectedCompanies, actualCompanies, action);
```

And for `Contact` you could simply do :

```
var action=  new Action<Contact,Contact>(ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was wondering why can't I directly say ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual? What is going wrong there?

Comment: I dont think he should have to instantiate the Action

Comment: When you do `ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual` , you are simply trying to "call" the function (which is syntactically incorrect without the parenthesis and parameters). However, when you pass it into the `Action` delegate, it takes the `method` as paramter without needing to explicitly declare a custom delegate. The encapsulated method must correspond to the method signature that is defined by this delegate. See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: `ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual` does not call the function, because it has no parenthesis. It *is* a syntactically correct way of passing reference to a function, saying a function without the parenthesis, and it is used a lot in C#

Comment: In that case it is like calling the `function`,(just to illustrate)  and I know it is also used as a way of passing reference. If you look at my answer, I have done the same, I have passed `ObjectComparer.AssertAreEqual` as a parameter to the `Action` instance. The parameter thus passed encapsulates the method that corresponds to the method signature defined by the delegate.